# Random record from the table

Tags: mysql, random

I have customer table with 10 columns. In the table customer id is repeated. I need to take only one record every customer but randomly.

Let suppose  customer table contain total 10000 records. But distinct customers is only 500.

So i need only 500  distinct customer data randomly.

I am using mysql 5.7.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a SQL-based example here. Why can't you just pick a `RAND()` customer record?

Comment: In 5.7, this is surprisingly tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------------+
| id | customer_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |
|  3 |           3 |
|  4 |           5 |
|  5 |           3 |
|  6 |           2 |
|  7 |           1 |
|  8 |           4 |
|  9 |           5 |
| 10 |           2 |
| 11 |           3 |
| 12 |           1 |
| 13 |           4 |
+----+-------------+

SELECT id
     , customer_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , customer_id
            , CASE WHEN @prev=customer_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=customer_id
         FROM 
            ( SELECT id
                   , customer_id
                FROM my_table  
               ORDER 
                  BY customer_id
                   , RAND()
            ) x
         JOIN (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
     ) n
 WHERE i = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY customer_id;

-- sample output, different each time --    
+----+-------------+
| id | customer_id |
+----+-------------+
| 12 |           1 |
| 10 |           2 |
|  3 |           3 |
|  8 |           4 |
|  9 |           5 |
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to ORDER BY RAND() because that will be extremely slow for a large table because it will actually sort all of those random records.

Instead pick a random int less than the number of rows in the table (random_num_less_than_row_count) and do this which is faster but not perfect.

```
SELECT * FROM atable LIMIT $random_num_less_than_row_count, 1
```

Or if u have a primary key that is an auto_increment you can pick a random int less than the highest id in the table (random_num_less_than_last_id) do the following which is pretty fast.

```
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE id >= $random_num_less_than_last_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

I did a >= and an ORDER BY id ASC so that if you are missing ids you'll still get a result. But if you have many large gaps you need the slower first option above.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about it but it is a beginner level query which might to get the desired result

SELECT Distinct column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 500

PS: This code isn't in mysql 5.7. And if anyone have a better query more than happy to get corrected